# What is the chemical formula of KIT-6?

Tags: nomenclature, catalysis

I have seen KIT-6 used in literature as a catalyst support, but cannot find the chemical formula for it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

According to original paper [(1)](https://dx.doi.org/10.1039/B306504A), KIT-6 is a highly ordered cubic $Ia3d$ silica ($\ce{SiO2}$) templated by [Pluronic P123](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pluronic_P-123) ($\ce{[EO20PO70EO20]}$) block-copolymer surfactant. As a source of $\ce{Si}$, tetraethoxysilane (TEOS) or sodium silicate are primarily used.

(1) Kleitz, F.; Choi, S. H.; Ryoo, R.; *Chem. Commun.* **2003,** *0* (17), 2136–2137. DOI: [10.1039/B306504A](https://dx.doi.org/10.1039/B306504A)

Answer (score 11):

KIT-6 is a mesoporous silica, the chemical formula is the same for all silica which is $\ce{(SiO2)_n}$. The tridimensional structure though is usually represented as

[image]

Answer (score -3):

According to this data sheet ([LINK](https://www.acsmaterial.com/media/catalog/product/s/d/sds_kit-6_1.pdf)) is SiO2.